# Angular2 Class undefined after calling API via http.get and receiving the correct JSON back

Tags: json, angular, amazon-web-services, typescript

I have the following code (based on the Angular2 Hero example) and I am trying to get a JSON API call (AWS) converted into a TypeScript class.

The code returns no errors, and I can see that the object is there when I look at response.json() but the class product remains undefined, any ideas?

Code in the service file...

```
  getProduct(id: number): Promise<Product> {
    const url = `${this.ProductsUrl}/${id}`;
    console.log(url);
    return this.http.get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().data as Product)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Code in the component file...

```
  ngOnInit(): void {    
    this.route.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => this.productsService.getProduct(+params['id']))
      .subscribe(product => this.product = product);
  }
```

The class...

```
export class Product {
  Instock: boolean;
  Description: string;
  CategoryId: number;
  Id: number;
  ColourOptions: string[];
  Name: string;
}
```

The JSON returned from the API call...

```
{
"Instock":true,
"Description":"This is a test description.",
"CategoryId":1,"
Id":1,
"ColourOptions":["Red","Gold","Green"],
"Name":"Test"
}
```

Comment: you can't subscribe to a `Promise`

Comment: This looks right

Comment: eddyP23, do you mean the code looks correct as is? n00dle - I took the code from the hero example on the Angular2 site, is it incorrect?

Comment: thanks all, working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`switchMap`'callback must return an `Observable` not a `Promise`, so edit `getProduct` to return a `Observable` instead:

```
 getProduct(id: number): Observable<Product> {
    const url = `${this.ProductsUrl}/${id}`;
    console.log(url);
    return this.http.get(url)
      .map(response => response.json().data as Product)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```